# How to add event to a hyperlink click and get the rowindex of the clicked object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a Sharepoint 2013 list what is a html table. There is a column with hyperlinks. I would like to fire an event if the user click on any of the hyperlinks in this column and get the rowindex of the clicked hyperlink. Everything is auto generated by SP so it is a mess and looks like no id at the links. A part of the html of the hyperlink's table: (I hope this is enough to determinate the rowindex somehow)

```
<td id="scriptWPQ2">
 <table onmousedown="return OnTableMouseDown(event);" summary="TestList" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" o:webquerysourcehref="&amp;XMLDATA=1&amp;RowLimit=0&amp;View=%7BEA3CDF07%2D1A28%2D4A44%2DBCB2%2D01F7D45A76C0%7D" border="0" cellspacing="0" dir="none" onmouseover="EnsureSelectionHandler(event,this,14)" cellpadding="1" id="{7632DCD3-4F1B-4F8E-AC8C-FB9C4372CD3D}-{EA3CDF07-1A28-4A44-BCB2-01F7D45A76C0}" class="ms-listviewtable" handledeleteinit="true">
  <tbody>
   <tr class=" ms-itmHoverEnabled ms-itmhover" oncontextmenu="return ShowCallOutOrECBWrapper(this, event, false)" iid="14,312,0" id="14,312,0" setedgeborder="true">
    <td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">
     <a href="/sites/Registry">copy</a> //no id here :(
```

Additionaly one more problem is that the table shows only 30 element by default and there is a next button at the bottom of the page what if pressed the table shows the next 30 element. So the click event should fire even after the button is pressed. I could get the rowindex by clicking on any element of the tabe, but this somehow worked only on the first 30 items:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("tr").click(function (){
        alert($("tr").index(this));
    });
});
```

My final goal is to read all other items from the clicked row and bring them to the page where to the hyperlink is redirect. Sadly I have no experience with JS and already wasted several hours for fails, so pls lend me a hand! Thank you very much for your kind help!

When works correctly with the suggested code from the first answer:

[image]

Where still work after the 2. page is loaded:

[image]

Comment: Are there links only in that column, or are they in other columns too?

Comment: There are several columns, but only one column with hyperlinks.

Comment: The reason the click event is not firing is because `$("tr")` is not dynamic, so, when the table replaces all `<tr>`, the new elements have no listener. Also, the index would start from 0 again, is that what you are looking for? Or should the index start from 30?

Comment: I see. And yeah the index should start from 30 at the 2. page.

Comment: @Nefri: i have updated the ans for outer click..Please check whether it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how [event delegation/propagation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) works in jQuery:

```
$('table').on('click', 'a', function (e) {

  // Make sure the browser doesn't follow the link
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).parent().parent().index());
});
```

Even if you add new rows to the table body, clicking on the link will still reveal the row index.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/76sv8md8/5/)**

Here's how you do this in native JS:

```
// Attach an event listener to the table element
let table = document.querySelector('table');
table.addEventListener('click', checkRowOfAnchor, false);

function checkRowOfAnchor(e) {

  // check to see if the clicked element is a link
  // prevent the browser from following the link
  // log the row index to the console
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/76sv8md8/1/)**

Comment: Yeah I am using jquery. I try to undersand and test. Thanks you very much for the detailed comments.

Comment: Yeah, I rarely use jQuery nowadays so I wrote it in native JS first and then transpiled it :)

Comment: This one is woks even on the 2. page! I have no idea why it works, but I ll figure out from this point thanks you very much! :D

Comment: Basically because the event listener is on the table element. It will wait for events to bubble up from sub-elements like the anchors. So, the code checks to see if the clicked element is an anchor, prevents the link from being followed, then logs the row index.

Comment: For example if I would like to get the ID from the same row should I simply change ".index()" to ".attr('id')"?

Comment: Try it out in the demo examples by changing the code. That's what it's there for  :)

Comment: Sure! Thanks you! I improved a lot by this examples. Also thanks u very much all who suggested coedes!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the event listener is not dynamic. Also, because you want the index to be incremental, even when changing pages, the code is a little more complex.

You need to keep track of what page you are in, and the total number of rows per page. I also added some caching to elements that I think are not going to change.

(By *changing page* I mean when you click the *next button*)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $table = $('table'); // cache the table
    var $rows = null; // cache rows - we do this on the function below
    var totalRowsNum = 30; // this needs to stay the same even if the last page has less rows
    var currentPageNum = -1; // the page we are currently viewing

    // start at page 0
    onPageChange(0);

    // call this after you change page
    function onPageChange(newPageNum) {
        $rows = $table.find('tbody tr');
        currentPageNum = newPageNum;
    }

    $table.on('click', 'tbody tr a', function () {
        var index = (currentPageNum * totalRowsNum) + $rows.index(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.id` will give you the id of clicked `<tr>` and you can use `on()` to add event to dynamically added elements as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table tr").on('click',function (){
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

for getting the `id` of the `<tr>` on link click and not other elements, yhe following code will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $("table tr a").on('click',function (){
    alert($(this).parents('tr:last').attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Note i have used `tr:last` as you are having `table` inside `td` so might get other tr as well.

Comment: The event listener is not dynamic, so when the table changes, this would not work.

Comment: Is there a way to make it dynamic? My goal is to read all other items from the clicked row and bring them to the page where to the hyperlink is redirect.

Comment: i have updated the answer to get the dynamically added tr

Comment: Attach the event listener to the table. You'll catch all dynamically added rows then with event propagation.

Comment: As suggested by @Andy updated to listed to `table tr`

Comment: I tested this and somehow works only on the first page : /. I also feel this should be good, but probably someting of Sharepoint retardness mess with it. For example the URL get an addition: "#InplviewHashea3cdf07-1a28-4a44-bcb2-01f7d45a76c0=Paged%3DTRUE-p_ID%3D340-PageFirstRow%3D31" Can it be the problem? Or what should I check to determinate? No errors in the log.

Comment: Looks like if I click on the outer part of the tabe it is still works but give empty alerts. So it is not works only if I click on the columns of the table. "outerpart" I mean this table containt some additional buttons around the item columns area. I add an image of it for better undersating sec.

Comment: Note that this doesnt check to see if the element clicked on is a link.

Comment: I tested the new code. This rly fire only if I click on the hyperlink but it gets "undefined" as result. Also if I click on other clickable elements (like next button) on the form also fire, but if I go to the next page still not works. Haha very strange. And thanks you very much for supporting all! :)

Comment: bit wierd. need to check your HTML structure to identify the core issue

Answer (score -1):

hey use this code to get index of row from table

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table tr").click(function (){

    alert($(this).index());
});
```

});

You can also use the table id in place of table tag for fire event